# How to find the key of a song without a pitch reference?

Tags: key, absolute-pitch

For instance, if I play the middle C or any note before a song starts, I can instantly guess the key of the song(I think this is known as RP - relative pitch).

Another trick I've used is finding out the lowest note I can sing with my voice and use it as a "reference pitch" to guess the key of a song. However, sometimes I have soar throat etc. so this is not a reliable way to find the key.

So the question here is if I have no instrument around, how can I figure out the key of a song? Can you memorise a certain note(like the middle C) and go from there or how does one train to achieve such a thing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1169/is-there-a-way-to-develop-perfect-pitch  - see the answers there.

Comment: I don't think this question is about developing perfect pitch (but the answers there are definitely useful).

Comment: One possible cheat is if you can hear an air conditioner or other similar device: Electric devices usually hum at a consistent pitch within your electric grid (Which usually includes but can be more than the country you live in.) I attended a concert where the performer claimed that pitch is roughly Bb in the USA.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely memorize a pitch an use that as a reference.  I only have a passable sense of relative pitch but I've been able to memorize A440.

Like anything else, memorizing a pitch requires practising and testing.  When I started out I'd listen to a recording of an A440 sine wave, then grab my (out of tune) guitar and try to tune the A string to match, then check and adjust until it was in tune.  Once I was able to get it tuned quickly, I started doing the opposite — tuning first, trying to imagine the pitch in my head, and then verifying against the recording or with a tuner.  Once you're getting it perfect every time you can stop verifying all the time and make use of it!

Comment: How long did this take you? weeks, months, years?

Comment: @lobi Good question.  I believe it was less than 2 months.

Comment: Nice idea. I did it with the first note of a well known tune. If I don't keep doing it every few days, the skill tends to go off pitch, so keep checking!!

Comment: Matthew is right on here, just remember that just because he did it in 2 months, if it takes you longer don't stress on it, you will get it. If you play guitar try the low E or A first depending on whats easier to sing,

Comment: You can also relate it to your instrument instead of or in addition to a song: As a guitarist, there was a time when I knew E this way because of all the time spent tuning the guitar. I can attest that it does go away if you stop working on it.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is by choosing a note at the bottom of my vocal range as my reference point.  It is a very recognizable place in my vocal range because if I try to go lower, the sound quality suffers dramatically.  So you're going for the feeling and the timbre, not just recognition of the note.

If there's a string instrument in your vicinity, that could give you a clue as well.  You can get it to resonate sympathetically with certain notes.  That resonance is audible in a subtle way, and sometimes visible, too.

Comment: Doesn't your vocal range change a bit during the day or depending on your state of health? When I try to use the lower end of my voice as a reference pitch, I notice that in the morning my lowest note might be about a whole tone lower than later in the day. When I have a cold it's even more ...

Comment: Me too.  And I just noticed that the OP noticed this too -- oops!  - - -  At any rate, the fact that there's a pattern, and the fact that most tunes aren't written in keys with tons of sharps or flats, can help.  - - -  I suppose one could carry around a little circular pitch pipe, if all else fails.

Answer (score 0):

No, without a pitch reference you can't tell.  But there are many ways to find a pitch reference, including "perfect pitch".

And, once you have that reference, "guessing" doesn't come into it.  You know for sure!

Answer (score -1):

My solution is to hum along to the song for a minute to get the feel (vibe), and then hum one a constant note which will most likely be the root or a perfect fifth above the root.

Then play each key on your instrument whilst humming until you find a match.  Once the root is found the key will most likely be minor if its modern music.

If this fails and your song is digital run it through detection software
[Free software link](http://www.pcdj.com/keyfinder-free-key-detection-software/)